# Removing a field from a Linked List (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, list, data-structures, structure

I have a one way linked list:

```
s=struct('field1', value1, 'field2', value2, 'field3', value3, 'next',[])
s=struct('field1', value3, 'field2', value5, 'field3', value6, 'next', s)
```

How do I remove the 'next' field so that my linked list becomes a standard structure array, like so?

```
s(1)=struct('field1', value1, 'field2', value2, 'field3', value3)
s(2)=struct('field1', value3, 'field2', value5, 'field3', value6)
```

I have tried the rmfield command but I get a 1x1 structure array, but I want, in this example, a 1x2 structure array.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to first aggregate all of your structs together. You could use a recursive function to do this. Then you can call `rmfield` on the array of structs. You could also even combine the two at the same time.

```
function S = flattenList(S)
    if isempty(S.next)
        S = rmfield(S, 'next');
    else
        S = cat(2, rmfield(S, 'next'), flattenList(S.next));
    end
end
```

As pointed out in the comments, since we are constantly appending data to the output, it can be slow for larger lists. We could determine the expected output size and then fill it within the loop.

This approach would allow you to pre-allocate the output.

```
function output = flattenList(S)

    % Determine how big to make the output
    tmp = S;
    count = 1;
    while ~isempty(tmp.next)
        count = count + 1;
        tmp = tmp.next;
    end     

    % Pre-allocate the output
    output = repmat(rmfield(S(1), 'next'), [1 count]);

    tmp = S;
    count = 1;
    while true
        output(count) = rmfield(tmp, 'next');
        if isempty(tmp.next)
            break;
        else
            tmp = S.next;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Note - this risks being very slow for a large list. Better to have a preallocated space, and populate recursively.

Comment: wouldn't it be more useful to advise that this isn't really a linked list and that the proper way to create one is via a handle subclass?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou That's not really the question here. Theoretically the user wants to flatten a linked list that they've already created.

Comment: @JayP That's essentially what the second bit of code is doing.

Comment: @Suever I'm just saying, this smells of [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Presumably he's just trying to implement a Linked List structure, and this isn't the way to do it. :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Well there are better ways to do it for sure, but I'm not sure that this doesn't qualify as a linked list. It's just an immutable linked list

Comment: @JayP There is a full demo by The Mathworks [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example--implementing-linked-lists.html)

Comment: @JayP You could easily determine the "previous" field if you wanted to put it in a handle-based linked list. You'd do it as you created the array.

Comment: @JayP Ok well the above solutions should both be able to get you what you need.

Comment: @JayP if this worked for you, consider marking it as the solution